# How to add custom items in Linq Query or Result of Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

ok. i have this query. It works fine.

```
var result = from c in displayedCategories 
             select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, c.Description};
```

I am using code first approach in EF.

But i want Extra Static Data to Be Added like html tags like input tags or etc..

so i tried like this.

```
var result = from c in displayedCategories 
             select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, c.Description,
                            ActionButtons = "SomeAction" };
```

but i am getting this error

> The name "ActionButtons" does not exist in the current context

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first linq query returns an array:

```
select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, c.Description}
```

did you mean anonymous type? (no brackets [])

```
select new { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, c.Description, ActionButtons = "SomeAction" }
```

array elements can't have names:

```
select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CategoryID), c.Name, c.Description, "SomeAction"}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Sir, The Last One you suggested worked for me great. :)